# Want to enlarge my Jquery slider central picture

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Hi I am working on a photo slider using Jquery. My slider works perfectly, however I'd like to enlarge my slider central picture, for example

by adding 20px of width and height so that it will look like the IOS Album library. When you slide right it will make the previous central picture as its normal size and enlarge the new central one. I have made my slider on => http://jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/4/ .

If someone can tell me how to make this features that I have already started on the link above. Thank you ?

#### JS

```
var index = 0;

$('.next').click(function(){
var photoWidth = parseInt($(".mf1_ui li:eq("+index+")").css("width"),10);
if(index != 0) photoWidth += 2;

console.log(photoWidth);
if(-(parseInt($(".mf1_ui").css("left"),10)) < (parseInt($(".mf1_ui").css("width"),10) -  288)){
    
  $( '.mf1_ui' ).animate({
      left: "-="+photoWidth+"px"
  }, {
      duration: 1000,
      queue : false,
      step: function( now, fx ){
      }
  });
 index++;  
}
});
 $('.previous').click(function(){
    var photoWidth = parseInt($(".mf1_ui li:eq("+(index -   1)+")").css("width"),10);
    if(index != 0) photoWidth += 2; 
    
    if(parseInt($(".mf1_ui").css("left"),10) <= 0){
      $( '.mf1_ui' ).animate({
        left: "+="+photoWidth+"px"
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue : false,
        step: function( now, fx ){
        } 
      }); 
      index--;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Any suggestion as I have already started programming in on JSfiddle

Comment: No one knows how to male that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have finally solved my problem with the slider, now the central picture is enlarged when you slide. the thing is I cannot verticaly center the central picture. If someone can tell me how to center it vertically to have a 3D effect.
My slider => http://jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/7/

Thanks

```
.wrapper{
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 288px;
height:108px;
left: 100px;
top: 100px;
}
ul{
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   float: left;
   height: 100px;
  }
li{
   float: left;
   height: 88px;
   padding: 2px 1px;
  }
ul li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
 .previous{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:38px;
  background-color:black;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor:pointer;    
}
.next{
width:20px;
height:20px;
position: absolute;
right:0px;
top:38px;
background-color:black;
z-index: 2;
cursor:pointer;
}
```